# export resultset to a text file in java with dialog

Tags: java, export-to-text

i am having a resultset and i have to write all the data available in resultset to a text file and populate the same to user for downloading.

i have done the below code to export to excel using poi, same way how to do for text file.

```
if(exportTo.equals("excel"))
        {
            response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + reportName + ".xls\"");
            try {
                HSSFWorkbook hwb = new HSSFWorkbook();
                HSSFSheet sheet = hwb.createSheet(reportName); 
                HSSFRow row = null;

                HSSFHeader header = sheet.getHeader();
                header.setCenter("POC");
                header.setLeft("POC");
                header.setRight(HSSFHeader.font("Stencil-Normal", "Italic") +
                                HSSFHeader.fontSize((short) 16) + reportName);

                //to add water mark
                /*HSSFPatriarch dp = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
                HSSFClientAnchor anchor = new HSSFClientAnchor
                    (0, 0, 1023, 255, (short) 2, 4, (short) 13, 26);
                HSSFTextbox txtbox = dp.createTextbox(anchor);
                HSSFRichTextString rtxt = new HSSFRichTextString("POC");
                HSSFFont draftFont = hwb.createFont();
                draftFont.setColor((short) 27);
                draftFont.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_NORMAL);
                draftFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 192);
                draftFont.setFontName("Verdana");
                rtxt.applyFont(draftFont);
                txtbox.setString(rtxt);
                txtbox.setLineStyle(HSSFShape.LINESTYLE_NONE);
                txtbox.setNoFill(true);*/

                HSSFCellStyle style = hwb.createCellStyle();
                style.setBorderTop((short) 6); // double lines border
                style.setBorderBottom((short) 1); // single line border
                style.setFillBackgroundColor(HSSFColor.GREY_25_PERCENT.index);

                HSSFFont font = hwb.createFont();
                font.setBoldweight((short) 700);

                // Create Styles for sheet.
                HSSFCellStyle headerStyle = hwb.createCellStyle();
                headerStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GREY_25_PERCENT.index);
                headerStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
                headerStyle.setFont(font);
                headerStyle.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
                headerStyle.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
                headerStyle.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
                headerStyle.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
                headerStyle.setAlignment((short) 2);

                // create Title for the sheet
                HSSFCellStyle titleStyle = hwb.createCellStyle();

                HSSFFont titleFont = hwb.createFont();
                titleFont.setFontName(HSSFFont.FONT_ARIAL);
                titleFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 15);
                titleFont.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
                titleFont.setColor(HSSFColor.BLUE.index);
                titleStyle.setFont(titleFont);
                titleStyle.setAlignment((short)2);

                row = sheet.createRow((short)1);
                HSSFCell secondCell = row.createCell((short) 0);
                secondCell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(reportName).toString());
                secondCell.setCellStyle(titleStyle);    
                sheet.addMergedRegion(new Region(1, (short)0, 1, (short)headerCount));

                int sno=0;
                HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short)4);
                for (Iterator it = headerMap.keySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                    String headerName = (String) headerMap.get(it.next());
                    HSSFCell headerCell = rowhead.createCell((short)sno);
                    headerCell.setCellStyle(headerStyle);
                    headerCell.setCellValue(headerName);
                    sno++;
                }

                HSSFCellStyle rowStyle=hwb.createCellStyle();
                rowStyle.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
                rowStyle.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
                rowStyle.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
                rowStyle.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
                rowStyle.setAlignment((short) 2);

                row = custDAO.creadExcelTable(query, sheet, row,rowStyle);
                hwb.write(response.getOutputStream());
                response.flushBuffer();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
public HSSFRow creadExcelTable(String query,HSSFSheet sheet,HSSFRow row,HSSFCellStyle rowStyle ){
        int numberOfColumns=0,sno=0,index=5,iterator=1;
        Connection connection = getConnection();
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                PreparedStatement reportTablePS = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                ResultSet reportTable_rst = reportTablePS.executeQuery();
                ResultSetMetaData reportTable_rsmd = reportTable_rst.getMetaData();
                numberOfColumns = reportTable_rsmd.getColumnCount();
                int i =0;
                while (reportTable_rst.next()) {
                     row = sheet.createRow((short)index);
                     sheet.setColumnWidth((short)index, (short)100);

                    /* if(i == 0){
                         i = 1;
                         rowStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.BLUE_GREY.index);
                         rowStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
                         System.out.println("BLUE_GREY");
                     }
                    else {
                        i = 0;
                        System.out.println("LEMON");
                        rowStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.LEMON_CHIFFON.index);
                        rowStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
                    }*/

                     HSSFCell serialCell = row.createCell((short)sno);
                     serialCell.setCellStyle(rowStyle);
                     serialCell.setCellValue(iterator);

                            for (int columnIterator = 1; columnIterator <= numberOfColumns; columnIterator++) {
                                 String column = reportTable_rst.getString(columnIterator);
                                 sheet.setColumnWidth((short)columnIterator, (short)3000);
                                 HSSFCell rowCell = row.createCell((short)columnIterator);
                                 rowCell.setCellStyle(rowStyle);
                                 rowCell.setCellValue(column);
                            }
                            index++;
                            iterator++; 
            }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                try {
                    closeConnection(connection, null, null);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return row;
    }
```

now i have done updto this and really don't know how to go about

```
 if(exportTo.equals("text")){
            response.setContentType("text/plain");
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + reportName + ".txt\"");
            try {

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

        }
```

this one for creating file in a specified location

```
Writer writer = null;

try {
    String text = "This is a text file";

    File file = new File("write.txt");
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
    writer.write(text);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (writer != null) {
            writer.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but i want to export the file with dialog, Please help me how to go about.

Regards

Comment: What does "export file with dialog" mean and how does it differ from what you do for Excel export?

Comment: i get data from database and write them using poi and export it, when the user clicks on export to excel, the save/open dialog is opened with the file.i want to do the same for text file also, my problem is how to write data to stream and set it for export

Comment: Set the content-type to `text/plain`. Do you understand how the "export to excel" code works?

Comment: yes i have understood, and set the `content-type to text/plain` also but i don't know how to set the data to outputstream

Comment: In the excel section you do `response.getOutputStream()`. Do the same thing and write your data to the output stream.

Comment: @JimGarrison thanks for the post, this is where i am facing problem, if you don't mind, would you please post some sample code for me to understand? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you don't get a dialog box, because your browser can handle text files by itself.
The browser reads the MIME type of the http response (which has been set with `response.setContentType("text/plain");`)
Most browsers open html, images and text themselves and redirect other file types like audio, pdf's or Office documents to other applications.
So you may need to adjust your browser settings.